# Return records from table 1 left join table 2 even if where condition fails

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables (Subjects, Student)

```
Subjects-> SubjID, NAME
Students->ID, Name, SubjID

Subjects
   SubjID Name

    1 | Maths

Students
   ID   NAME, SubjID    
   11 | XYZ | 1
```

**What I need to have ->**

Return Subject details with ID 1, and also return if student with id 10 has this subject.

**This is my query so far.**

```
select * from subjects sb
left join students st on st.SubjID=sb.SubjID

where sb.SubjID=1 and (st.ID is null or st.ID=10)
```

**Result what I get is:**

If Subject 1 is not associated with (any student or associated with student with id 10 I get result.

But if Subject 1 is associated with other student with id say 11 but not with id 10, I dont get any results.

**What I need is:** Even if subject is associated with some other student I should get result of Subject table.

Is there any way we can achieve this??

Comment: I think you are overcomplicating this.  Instead of verbally describing the output you want, can you instead show us a table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to see student records for anyone other than ID=10, move the condition from `WHERE`, which filters rows post-join, to `ON`, which filters only rows in the `students` table:

```
select * from subjects sb
left join students st on st.SubjID=sb.SubjID and st.ID=10
where sb.SubjID=1
```